How to find max score for all intervals?
I ran into this problem while working on a project, and was wondering a optimal way to solve this:
Say I have the following intervals with scores, I want to find the max score within the intervals, at any moment:
3-8 20
4-10 40
8-12 10
9-13 20

The result should be 40+10+20 = 70
3-8 and 4-10 overlap at 4-8 with a total 'score' of 40+20 = 60
4-10, 8-12, and 9-13, all overlap at 9-10 with a score of 40+10+20 = 70
Obviously we have other overlaps like every interval by itself,
or 8-12 and 9-13 excluding 4-10, but those dont yield a maximum.
I also ideally would want to return the overlap that yielded the max amount,
which in this case would be the 9-10 interval,
which corresponds to the interval at which all 3 intervals that yielded the max score amount share.
What would be a good algorithm to solve this?
My initial idea was to sort by starting point, and then check if the previous interval was overlapping (which is easy enough), the problem I quickly ran into was that say we have the following:
3-9 20
4-10 40
8-12 10
9-13 30

As we iterate, we consider 3-9 overlapping with 4-10 giving 60, then 3-9, 4-10, and 8-12 overlapping at 8-9 giving 70. Then, however, when we find 9-13, we need to somehow stop considering 3-9, and now look at 4-10, 8-12, 9-13 overlapping, giving 80, and overlapping at 9-10. Is it possible to maybe do a sliding window?

Associate starting points with positive scores and ending points with negative scores. Sort all points together, and keep track of the cur & max cumulative sum & the start/end associated with the max sum.
If you want single-point high scores to count then in your sort, break ties in favor of positives, otherwise break ties in favor of negatives.
E.g.
3-8 20
4-10 40
8-12 10
9-13 20

Time  Score  Cur   Max
 3    +20    20    20
 4    +40    60    60
 8    +10    70    70  # Tie broken in favor of positive
 8    -20    50    70
 9    +20    70    70
10    -40    30    70
12    -10    20    70
13    -20     0    70

